# How to check kernel version in Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel

How can I check my kernel version in my Makefile ??

Based on the kernel version I want to select some of the header files accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

```
KVER = $(shell uname -r)
KMAJ = $(shell echo $(KVER) | \
sed -e 's/^\([0-9][0-9]*\)\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*.*/\1/')
KMIN = $(shell echo $(KVER) | \
sed -e 's/^[0-9][0-9]*\.\([0-9][0-9]*\)\.[0-9][0-9]*.*/\1/')
KREV = $(shell echo $(KVER) | \
sed -e 's/^[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/')

kver_ge = $(shell \
echo test | awk '{if($(KMAJ) < $(1)) {print 0} else { \
if($(KMAJ) > $(1)) {print 1} else { \
if($(KMIN) < $(2)) {print 0} else { \
if($(KMIN) > $(2)) {print 1} else { \
if($(KREV) < $(3)) {print 0} else { print 1 } \
}}}}}' \
)

ifeq ($(call kver_ge,3,8,0),1)
echo great or equal than 3.8.0
else
echo less than 3.8.0
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are coding some application, you might do

```
 KERNELVERSION=$(shell uname -a)
```

or some other shell command, perhaps `cat /proc/version`

For a kernel module, see [cnicutar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15063313/841108).

Comment: How can I comapre the same and confirm it in MAKEFILE ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 50 reputation so I can't answer Mr. voght's comment in a comment (upvote me so I can!) but I can do so just as another answer, so here goes.

The code uses the shell built-in to shell out (*bash*) commands like *uname* and *echo*, and assign variable-like macros such as `KVER` to the result. *uname* provides the kernel version, the code goes on to use the unix *sed* (stream editor; *man sed* for more) to extract each of the major, minor and rev numbers from the results and assign them to discrete variable-like macros. Then he assigns a macro name, `kver_ge` to the process (using *awk*, *test*, and *if* shell built-ins) of testing whether the kernel version is greater than the one provided as an argument.
Pretty cool, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to first assign a variable true/false (actually 1/0 in example below) by a test in Makefile and then use ifeq command like the answer from goodgoodstudydaydayup, here is a simpler approach:

```
KERNEL_GT_5_4 = $(shell expr `uname -r` \> "5.4.0-0-generic")
all:
ifeq (${KERNEL_GT_5_4},1)
    echo greater than 5.4.0-0-generic
else
    echo less than 5.4.0-0-generic
endif
```

Comment: as a string 5.4 would be greater than 5.10 ! You need a more complex approach like the one from @goodgoodstudydaydayup